# How I convert a number to 3 decimal points?

Tags: javascript, syntax, decimal

I'm having a problem where I can't convert numbers to something like "0.037", given the case where I have 37 as one of these numbers, without this affecting larger numbers like "2015", which in turn manage to become "2.015".

I tried approaches like:

```
myNumber = parseFloat(myNumber.toFixed(3));
myNumber = (myNumber / 1000).toFixed(3);
```

i keep having my whole number the same "37" not "0.037"

The most efficient approach to the case so far has been parseFloat with toFixed, however, as stated, it only works on numbers that are larger, not integers like "0" and "37".

Comment: `(37 / 1000).toFixed(3)` gives `0.037`, you need to show a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what do you want the input and output be. You should give some additional examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just a simple syntax error, you need to chain operations in JS like this:

```
let myNumber = parseFloat(yourNumberHere).toFixed(3);
```

or like this :

```
let myNumber = parseFloat(your number);
myNumber.toFixed(3);
```